# Using .map with numbers not an array, or ignoring the first parameter in a map and just using index

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

I am making a react app and I was trying to do a map to loop over and display multiple images. I was trying to make this dynamic so that if the number of images is different in each folder it will display the appropriate amount of images.

```
<div className="rotating-gallery-image-container" style={{transform: currentTransform} as React.CSSProperties}>
   {[...Array(numberOfPictures)].map((x, index) =>
       <span style={{ "--i": index } as React.CSSProperties} key={index}>
          <img
              src={`/images/gallery-images/${imageGroup}/${index}.jpg`}
          />
       </span>
    )}
</div>
```

I'm only used to mapping over arrays, but in this case numberOfPictures is just a number. Is there a better way for mapping over this or doing a foreach?

Also the only way to get the index is to have it as the second parameter but then I don't have any use for the "x" in this situation. I end up with the warning that x is declared but its value is never read, which I would want to get rid of.

Is there a way to just have the index and no first parameter in the map? Or a better way to render multiple times based on a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better to map over you pictures `Array` if it's possible, especially if those pictures have an `id` which you could use as a `key` inside your loop instead of the `index`.

In all cases you can use an underscore if you don't need to use the first param to avoid the warning.

```
[...Array(numberOfPictures)].map((_, index) => {
    ...
})
```

Comment: Ah I was unaware you could use underscore when not using a certain parameter. Thank you!

I actually don't have a picture array. I just have a folder with pictures that I actually just made their names like 0, 1, 2, etc. I know usually you would have names and ids and such but in this particular use case my images have no particular order or need to differentiate. I basically just wanted it to say scroll through and display the images in this folder.

So it is why when I import it is just /directory/${imageNumber}.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to put the *index* in key, as [react's document](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists) says:

> You might be tempted to use an item’s index in the array as its key.
> In fact, that’s what React will use if you don’t specify a key at all.
> But the order in which you render items will change over time if an
> item is inserted, deleted, or if the array gets reordered. Index as a
> key often leads to subtle and confusing bugs.

The best approach is, using a unique id from the data you are trying to map over, then you'll have to use the *x* and you don't get the mentioned error.

Comment: Yes I knew that it is not best practice to use the index as a key. This is not a situation where I have an array of items with IDs or other identifiers, this is essentially a for loop over a set of numbers. So the key does not matter for me.